# Capacitor on control voltage for 555 timer

Tags: capacitor, 555

I was trying to tinker around with a 555 timer, but I don't have any 100 nF capacitors for pin 5 the control voltage. Can I use a 68 nF capacitor? I also thought about stacking two capacitors in parallel to get a close-enough value. Is a 68 nF capacitor safe?

Comment: 68nF is surely fine. 2x68nF is better. The answer here says 10nF is enough: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/545253/7555-optional-control-voltage-capacitor . All this capacitor does is prevent power supply ripple from influencing the 1/3 and 2/3 threshold voltages.

Comment: It just aids in stabilizing the inputs for the 2 comparator's, is that right?

Comment: Exactly. That's all it does

Comment: Does this answer your question? [7555 optional control voltage capacitor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/545253/7555-optional-control-voltage-capacitor)